# Change font size & font family (long name) on Outlook mail through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In addition to the question : [Change HTML email body font type and size in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200910/change-html-email-body-font-type-and-size-in-vba), i would like to know how can i change both the font size & the font family with long name. 
Here is my code which change only the font size:

```
strbody = "<BODY style=" & Chr(34) & "font-size:12pt;" & Chr(34) & "font-family:Times New Roman" & Chr(34) & ">" & "Hello" & "</BODY>"
```

When i remove the font size from the code it's indeed change the font-family.

Thanks for your assistance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using single quotes within the quoted string. It's allowed in HTML styles.

```
strbody = "<BODY style='font-size:12pt;font-family:Times New Roman'>" & "Hello" & "</BODY>"
```