# VBA Change the Font of the mail

Tags: html, vba, outlook, ms-word, html-email

I created a vba code but the font and the size of the mail are incorrect. I would like Calibri 11 but it's Calibri 10 for the first line (Hello) and Verdana 10 for the rest. How to proceed?

```
Sub mail_outlook()

Dim OutApp As Object 
Dim OutMail As Object 

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail 
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    .Display 

    .To = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    
    .HTMLBody = "Hello, " & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please find in attachment the Report." & "<br>" & "We remain available should you have any questions." & .HTMLBody
    .CC = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    .BCC = "" 
    .Subject = "Report"

    
End With 

Set OutMail = Nothing 
Set OutApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: As aside, you don't need separate strings for eech "<br>" - just include them in the HTML string `.HTMLBody = "Hello,<br><br>Please find in attachment the Report.<br>We remain available should you have any questions."  & .HTMLBody`. As strings are immutable, a new string is being created everytime you append to the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the font size in the HTML:

```
"<font style=""font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;""> your content goes here</font>"
```

See [Change HTML email body font type and size in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200910/change-html-email-body-font-type-and-size-in-vba) for more information.

Also you may use the Word object model for doing that programmatically. The [WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information. For example, in Word you could use the following sequence of property calls:

```
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Font.Size = 12
Selection.Font.Name = "Georgia"
```